# How do i make json object as an json array

Tags: javascript, json

I've a json returned as part of my api call and it looks like below.

```
{
  'D1': {
    'name': 'Emp1',
    'Age':22
  },
  'D2': {
    'name': 'Emp2',
    'Age':43
  },
};
```

I want to convert this into an array. i.e. in the below format.

```
[
  'D1': {
    'name': 'Emp1',
    'Age':22
  },
  'D2': {
    'name': 'Emp2',
    'Age':43
  },
];
```

I'm trying to do it using the below code.

```js
let obj = {
  'D1': {
    'name': 'Emp1',
    'Age':22
  },
  'D2': {
    'name': 'Emp2',
    'Age':43
  },
};
 
 let wholeArray = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
 
 console.log(wholeArray);
```

But it is stripping off the outer JSON keys.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how to get the expected output.

Comment: The array you shared is neither valid Javascript nor valid JSON.

Comment: the wanted format is not valid. do you want only values of the objects?`

Comment: [There is not such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Why do you want to do this conversion? What benefits do you expect from this? It looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You want to convert an object to an array but you want this array to behave like an object.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I need to run a `foorEach` on this output. so, wanted in array

Comment: Why not [`for (... in ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)?

Comment: Ok. Lemme try that out @ThomasSablik :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate the object into an array with only one key/value pair.

```js
let object = { D1: { name: 'Emp1', Age:22 }, D2: { name: 'Emp2', Age:43 } },
    array = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(pair => Object.fromEntries([pair]));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

> ```
> [
>   'D1': {
>     'name': 'Emp1',
>     'Age':22
>   },
>   'D2': {
>     'name': 'Emp2',
>     'Age':43
>   },
> ];
> ```

Simply does not exist. Arrays have no keys, objects do.

The most you could do is:

```
[
  {
    'D1': {
      'name': 'Emp1',
      'Age':22
    }
  },{
    'D2': {
      'name': 'Emp2',
      'Age':43
    }
  }
];
```

An array of objects with a single key.

One code variant for doing this:

```js
let obj = {
  'D1': {
    'name': 'Emp1',
    'Age':22
  },
  'D2': {
    'name': 'Emp2',
    'Age':43
  },
};
 
//let wholeArray = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
let wholeArray = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  let ret={};
  ret[key]=obj[key];
  return ret;
});
 
console.log(wholeArray);
```

Side remark: I see a lot of similar question in the past 2-3 days, people want "JSON array" with keys, and they also carefully put an "empty" comma at the end of their arrays. Are you guys coming from some course?